# dialog body center pains

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a dialog box im going to turn into a manual entry dialog for a select box.  I am having issues getting the text/input box to align vertically in the center.  here is the URL if you want to view.  Just select anything in the select box and you will see, I have made it taller for testing only.  Below is my dialog code. http://moconsultant.net and below that is my css the CSS is also used for a dialog alert system I built  MO

```
  $('.selectBox').change(function(){


        myDialogBox=" <div  title='Im a Manual Entry Box' class='dialogDiv'> Manual Entry:<input type='text' name='dialogName' id='dialogName' maxlength='40' class='dialogInput' ></div>"
        $(myDialogBox).dialog({
           autoOpen: true,
           width: 'auto',  
           height: '500',
           modal: true,
           fluid: true, //new option
            buttons:[               
                  {
            text: 'Retun',
             'class': 'return',
              click: function() {
               $(this).dialog( 'close' );

            myField.focus();myField.select();

             }
            }
            ], 
           close: function() {

           }
         });
         });
      }


/*mo alert*/

          .ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar
          {
         background-color: #0D3257;
        color: #ffffff;
        text-align: center;    
          }

          .ui-dialog
          {
             border: 3px solid #0D3257;
          }
          .ui-dialog .ui-dialog-title
          { 
            margin: .1em 16px .1em 0;
           text-align: center;
            float:none !important; 
          }
        .ui-dialog .ui-dialog-content  { 
     border: none; 
     background-color: #B0C4DE;
     color: #00549E;
     padding: 0;
     vertical-align:text-middle;
  }
  .ui-button.continue{
     color:green;
     font-family: Arial;
     font-size: 12px;
     font-weight: bold;  
     background-color:#F1F3F7;
     height:28px;
     Width:150px;
     padding-bottom: 5px;
     border-style:outset;
     border-color:#9BB7D9;
     filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient  
     (GradientType=0,StartColorStr='#F1F3F7',EndColorStr='#E2EEFD');
      }
   .ui-button.continue:hover {
    color:blue;
     }
     .ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane { 
    text-align: center;
}
    .ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane .ui-dialog-buttonset { 
    float: none;
     }
    .ui-button.return{
     color:green;
     font-family: Arial;
     font-size: 12px;
     font-weight: bold;
     background:#B0C4DE;
     text-align:center;
     height:28px;
     width:150px;
     outline: none;
     border:0px;
     filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient  
     (GradientType=0,StartColorStr='#F1F3F7',EndColorStr='#E2EEFD');
      }
    .ui-button.return:hover {
    color:blue;
     }
.ui-widget-header {
    background:#0D3257;
    border:0px;
}
.dialogDiv{

 text-align:center;
 padding-top: 22px; /* you can use a padding to vertically center*/
}


 .dialogInput{
 height: 15px;


 }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-to-align-text-vertically-center-in-div-with-css

Comment: this did not work but thank you

Comment: uploaded code to my site sorry I should have done that first

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZMQTY/)** on jsfiddle.net.

Set a CSS pseudo element to your wrapping div container, the div with the `id="ui-id-7"`, for example. The CSS pseudo element gets a `display: inline-block;`, a `height: 100%;` and a `vertical-align: middle;`. Don´t forget the `content: '';`. Now wrap your content to be aligned in another div container and set this one to `display: inline-block;` and `vertical-align: middle;`.

By the way, I would recommend to use a `label` element for the input label. So users are able to click on the label to set the focus to the input field. Works for all kind of input types.

HTML code:

```
<div class="dialogDiv ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content vertical-align-outer" id="ui-id-7" style="display: block; width: auto; min-height: 0px; max-height: none; height: 386px;">
    <div class="vertical-align-inner">
        <label for="dialogName">Manual Entry:</label>
        <input type="text" name="dialogName" id="dialogName" maxlength="40" class="dialogInput"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.vertical-align-outer:before {
    content: ' ';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.vertical-align-inner {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: thank you i'll give it a try when I get a minute, I like the label idea, I have never used THAT thanks  MO

Comment: to be honest I can't remember I was at that for hours and had made so many changes. it is not the code I am using though but most likely because it's all combined with other css I had out there